# pulseaudio broken after common fix for distortion

Tags: 20.04, sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa

I've had problems with audio distortion especially after suspend. Previously I could fix this using the following line:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

but it now started indicating that the reload did not take place.

So I searched around this Q/A site and found that the following line might do it.

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Now I do have system sounds, but the sound test or any other sound fails. To make matters worse, the system sounds are distorted as well.

I've noticed that the link to `/etc/pulse/client.conf.d/01-enable-autospawn.conf -> /run/pulseaudio-enable-autospawn` is now broken because the target is missing. That link was present before (I checked the folders before making changes).

Pulseaudio seems to be running (for the user), but it is missing cookies because I deleted them while trying to get pulse-audio to run.

I've already forcably removed alsa and pulseaudio and reinstalled it again, no change (also not in the link).

---

Update: forgot to mention that I've hooked up my speakers to my DisplayPort monitor. I use the default drivers for an Gigabyte AMD RX 580 with 3 monitors attached.

---

Relevant output of `inxi -Fz`:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-73-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.7 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING v: Rev 1.xx serial: <superuser/root required> 
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 2605 date: 08/06/2019 
CPU:       Topology: 8-Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           Speed: 3799 MHz min/max: 2200/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3800 2: 3800 3: 3801 4: 3800 5: 3799 6: 3800 7: 3800 
           8: 3799 9: 3820 10: 3799 11: 3812 12: 3800 13: 3797 14: 3800 15: 3799 16: 3800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] driver: amdgpu 
           v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10 DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-73-generic LLVM 11.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 
Audio:     Device-1: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-3: Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-73-generic
```

---

Update: now my sound is back but the Test button just doesn't work. Um, OK???

Comment: I hope somebody can help me fix this, because Ubuntu is useless to me without working sound.

Comment: Not likely. We don't even know which Ubuntu version you are running. Execute in terminal: `inxi -Fz` and paste the output into your question

Comment: Added. Interesting to see it is the intel driver, that may lead to some solution maybe (for the distortion anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.  The temporary fix is to open system monitor and kill pulseaudio process.  It fixes my distortion.  It does however, come back for me every couple of days.  That I cant answer